# What is it called when a Corporation purchases the rights to something to prevent it's production, to increase profit

Tags: economy, political-economy

What is it called, when a Large Business or Corporation sees that some product, invention, or medicine will destroy or reduce the size of their market or consumer base; and they either purchase the rights to it, or pay them not to make it; so that they can continue business or enlarge their profit.

I remember hearing about stuff like this happening multiple times, I can't remember the citations, nor can I remember if anyone actually gave a name to this phenomena.

If you can't find a name for it, I will accept a list of 2 or more occurrences as an answer.

Comment: Not a history question at all. Go ask [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Suggested migration to politics.se, as they're willing to cover non-historical macro economics.

Comment: I personally would like that migration, I was looking for stack economics can't believe I didn't find it. ty ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific word for it, but you can call it "buying out the competition" or "keeping a stranglehold on the market".

Answer (score 0):

We call it "unfriendly acquisition".